# Output global settings into application-wide javascript variable in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

the issue is - I need to output JSON variable on application bootstrap, which holds database records, like this:
SETTINGS.cities - will hold list of cities retrieved from the database,
SETTINGS.companies - will hold list of companies from the database...and so on..

the question is - what is the correct way to do this in ZF2? Where to collect all data from the database and where to output it to json?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish. What do you mean by output? Are you talking about actually returning a JSON view model, or simply adding inline JS to every page?  If it's the latter, you could create an event listener on the "render" event which gets the data you want and adds it to the view model for the layout as a variable.  Then in the layout, output your JS object based on the data that was passed in. With a little bit more detail, I might be able to help better.

Comment: Hi @ChandlerTi, I want to output the javascript variable, which will be available across all application. So in my javascript I want tp be able to refer to this variable to populate select dropdowns and so on. Currently I've created the view helper, which collects all the data I need end echoing json-encoded variable in layout.phtml. The result is what I need but I want to know the most correct solution for ZF2.

Comment: (Is your app already in ZF2 or are you converting from ZF1?) I don't necessarily see an inherent problem with this approach other than a view helper is often used for functionality you need in more than one place/view. I would probably do as I mentioned in my previous comment and use and event listener to inject the values into the layouts view model.  But if it ain't broke ;)

Comment: Yes, it is ZF2 from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a model of some sort that interacts with the db to get the settings. Then, in my module bootstrap grab that data from the model you made and place it into the layout view variable like this:

Your **onBootstrap method in Module.php**

```
// Create an event for pre dispatch
$eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'jsonSettings'),100);
```

Create the method there in **Module.php** (*or in your model*)

```
public function jsonSettings($event) {
    $viewModel = $event->getViewModel();

    $settings = new SettingsModel();
    $viewModel->setVariable('settings',$settings->getJson());
    return;
}
```

After that in your layout.phtml file you can access the settings with `$settings`